# Cannot connect MySQL in a Django project docker container

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

First, I installed Docker v4.20.1 in my Windows 10.

I can run docker compose successfully and their status are as the following.

```
D:\my_container>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                 NAMES
93d9c021200b   phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:8080->80/tcp      phpmyadmin
80c6e906cf7e   web          "./entrypoint.sh"         23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp                  web
31d5cce52752   db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   db
```

my phpmyadmin container can access mysql db successfully as the following screenshot.
[image]

If I run the django project in my host computer(Windows 10), it also connect mysql db successfully.
[image]

But If I try to run the django server in the container, it shows up the error message that it can't connect mysql db correctly.

The error logs:

```
root@80c6e906cf7e:/usr/src/app# python caravan/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 291, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 399, in get_new_connection
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 293, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1181, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 296, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/caravan/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/src/app/caravan/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1558, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2002, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_expression_indexes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 318, in supports_expression_indexes
    and self._mysql_storage_engine != "MyISAM"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 162, in _mysql_storage_engine
    return self.connection.mysql_server_data["default_storage_engine"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 541, in mysql_server_data
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 705, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 399, in get_new_connection
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 293, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1181, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 296, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (2003, "2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)", 'HY000')
root@80c6e906cf7e:/usr/src/app#
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml content:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    db:
        image: db
        container_name: db
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        volumes:
          - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - PMA_PORT=3306
            
    web:
        image: web
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./web:/usr/src/app
        depends_on:
            - db
            
volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

And my django project db connection settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'caravan',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
          'use_oure': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I have tried many times, but I still can't figure out what's wrong.
Could anyone give a hint?

Comment: Change the `'HOST': '127.0.0.1',` to `'HOST': 'DB',`

Answer (score 2):

Change `HOST` in `DATABASES` to `db`
because in docker, containers can communicate with each other by a dns name (docker compose service name) and in your case it is `db` not `127.0.0.1`